# Tool to remotely log (debug) React Native production app

Tags: react-native, debugging, logging

Is there some tool available for React Native to remotely debug or send logs from production app to me?
I want to use it to track what errors my test users getting without them need to interact with app.

Comment: Here is similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947480/react-native-collect-logs-remote/57690477#57690477

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about raygun?  This gives you an api to log your errors and then a portal to view them.  I use it on a project at work and it's worth looking at https://raygun.com/

Comment: Nice! But not cheap, tho :D

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for you which will be quite easy for you to implement. The first one I would suggest you is `react-native-firebase` and use it for pushing events to the analytics in firebase.

The second option would be `react-native-flurry-sdk` offered by yahoo flurry analytics which is also very easy and efficient.

If your app is on google play store already then you can use the build in crash reporting system which reports most of the errors but if you need something specific and in your own control like if you want the app to send you a specific error etc then its best to use `react-native-flurry-sdk`. you can get it from here:

https://github.com/flurry/react-native-flurry-sdk